# Create a Figure with a sequence of Balanced Binary Trees

Tags: trees

I would like make the attached image by Mathematica. 
someone who could help me?
Thank![image]

Comment: Or [CompleteKaryTree](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompleteKaryTree.html)

Comment: And at least but not last.., have you even tried anything? Like getting the coordinates of the points?

Comment: Now I just saw the comments ... thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 6):

Not a perfect match but a start

```
Partition[Table[Column[{"i = " <> ToString[2^(n - 1)], 
 CompleteKaryTree[n, 
  ImagePadding -> 
   10, (AbsoluteOptions[
     CompleteKaryTree[n, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10], 
     VertexCoordinates] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, -y})], 
 "\[Omega] = " <> ToString[n]}, Center], {n, 2, 5}], 2] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you have Version 9, you can use the `GraphLayout` suboptions as follows:

```
bbt[n_] := 
Labeled[GraphUnion[CompleteKaryTree[n], Graph[{UndirectedEdge[0, 1]}],
                   BaseStyle ->Directive[Opacity[1], Black, PointSize[.015]],
                   EdgeStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thick}], AspectRatio -> 1,
                   VertexShapeFunction -> "Point",  ImageSize -> 300,
                   GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 0,
                                   "Orientation" -> Bottom, 
                                   LayerSizeFunction -> (If[# == 1, 1, 2^(n - #)] &)}],
       {"i = " <> ToString[2^(n - 1)],"\[Omega] = " <> ToString[n]}, 
       {Top, Bottom}];

Row[bbt /@ Range[2,7], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't look the same on _v8_. None of the `GraphLayout` options seem to work for me.

Comment: @Öskå, right - these `GraphLayout` options are new-in-version-9.

Comment: Well, they seem to be very useful! You already have my +1

Comment: @Oska, thank you for the +.

Comment: Well, your output looks like what the OP desired, the raw one from `CompleteKaryTree` is getting flatter and flatter.